# Calculating the area of a quadrilateral which circumscribes a circle and the distance of a point lying inside it to all the vertices is given.

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> Given a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ circumscribed about a circle of diameter $1$. Inside $ABCD$, there is a point $M$ such that $|MA|^2 + |MB|^2+ |MC|^2 + |MD|^2= 2.$ Find the area of $ABCD$.

I've tried to solve this problem but I'm unable to do as I don't understand the use of the information of the distance of the point and how to use it, any help would be really appreciated!

answer=1

my process-

i couldn't start with this sum

Comment: One way is to simply guess a configuration which works by trying the simplest one possible: pick ABCD to be a square and see if it contains a point giving the desired sum. (I can confirm that it does.) What I don't know how to do is whether other quadrilaterals exist with this property; I haven't found any, but that's hardly dispositive.

Comment: I thought of doing it that way but I wanted a general solution which would work for all such quadrilaterals.

Comment: I think this could be solved using vectors. (I'm busy now, I'll try myself later.)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Please include in the post what you have tried.

Comment: The condition on the sum of squares should involve a circle whose center is the center of gravity of vertices A,B,C,D ; see the answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3081064/305862)

Comment: Circumscribed quadrilaterals have a certain number of properties, for example [this one](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/CircumQuadri.shtml#explanation)

Comment: I couldn't make any noticeable progress, i used a+c=b+d but it didn't get me anywhere

Comment: I tried using your method Jean Marie but im still unable to do the entire sum

Comment: If this have a unique solution, then the area has to be $1$ because a square of side $1$ with $M$ at center of circle satisfy the given condition.

Comment: One way to generalize this would be: Given such a quadrilateral $ABCD$ (known as a tangential quadrilateral in English), find the point $M$ which minimizes $|MA|^2+|MB|^2+|MC|^2+|MD|^2$. Along the way, one would hopefully show that this sum cannot be smaller than $2$ and that this is only achieved when $ABCD$ is square.

Answer (score 2):

Rename $A,B,C,D$ as $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ and extend indexing of everything by periodicity (i.e $P_0 = P_4, P_1 = P_5$ and so on).

Let $\ell_i = |MP_i|$. We are given $M$ is inside $ABCD$. So
$$\begin{align}\verb/Area/(ABCD) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^4\verb/Area/(MP_iP_{i+1}) \\
&\le \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^4 \ell_i \ell_{i+1} \le \frac14 \sum_{i=1}^4 (\ell_i^2 + \ell_{i+1}^2)\\ 
&= \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^4 \ell_i^2 = 1\end{align}$$
One the other direction, we know  among all quadrilaterals circumscribing a circle, the square has the smallest area${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$. In this case, the diameter of the circle is $1$ and the square circumscribing it has area $1$. This means

$$\verb/Area/(ABCD) \ge 1$$

Combine these, we have $\verb/Area/(ABCD) = 1$.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - For a proof, see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2478867).

Comment: [+1] Perfect answer !

Answer (score 1):

As you asked about explicitation of the method, here it is.

**It isn't still a solution,** but it connects point $M$ to the centroid $G$ of the vertices.

Let us rename vertices $A,B,C,D$ as $P_k$ for $k=1\cdots 4$.

Let

$$G=\frac14 \sum_{k=1}^4(P_k)$$

be their centroid.

Let us write the given constraint under a vectorial form by expanding it using dot product :

$$2=\sum_{k=1}^4(MP_k)^2=\sum_{k=1}^4\overrightarrow{MP_k}^2=\sum_{k=1}^4\overrightarrow{MG +GP_k}^2$$

$$2=\sum_{k=1}^4 \overrightarrow{MG}^2+2\sum_{k=1}^4(\overrightarrow{MG}.\overrightarrow{GP_k})+\sum_{k=1}^4(\overrightarrow{GP_k})^2$$

$$2=4(MG)^2+2 \overrightarrow{MG}.\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^4 \overrightarrow{GP_k}}_{0}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^4(\overrightarrow{GP_k})^2}_S$$

$$2=4(MG)^2+S \ \text{where} \ S:=\sum_{k=1}^4(\overrightarrow{GP_k})^2 >0,$$

giving a very strong constraint that I would translate into "point $M$ should be very close to centroid $G$".